# Is $P(W \geq z |V \geq y)=P(U-V \geq z |V \geq y)=P(U \geq z+y)$ correct?

Tags: probability, random-variables

Let $U,V,W=U-V$ random variables with $z,y \geq 0$

$$P(W \geq z |V \geq y)=P(U-V \geq z |V \geq y)=P(U \geq z+y)$$

Is it correct?

Answer (score 0):

Now, in general it's wrong. Note that 
$$ \def\P{\mathbf P} \P(U-V \ge z \mid V \ge y) 
  = \frac{\P(U-V \ge z, V \ge y)}{\P(V \ge y)} 
 $$
Now two things got wrong: (1) Note that $\{U - V \ge z\}\cap \{V \ge y\}$ is not the same as $\{U \ge y+z, V \ge y\}$, as if for example $V = 2y$, and $U-V = y+z$, then the second one is true, also the first event is wrong. (2) $U$ and $V$ need not to be independent.